# Query multiple tables using spring jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-data, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a requirement to query 5 tables, form a json based on the response and send to consumer.
Instead of querying one by one using jdbcTemplate, I would like to do single call and get all the response.

```
{
   "TableA":[
      {
          table rows as data
      }
   ],
   "TableB":[
      {
          table rows as data
      }
   ],
   "TableC":[
      {
          table rows as data
      }
   ],
   "TableD":[
      {
          table rows as data
      }
   ],
   "TableE":[
      {
          table rows as data
      }
   ]
}
```

Since am new to spring jdbc finding difficult to implement it.

Comment: SQL UNION maybe, or JOIN?

Comment: It depends on what data you need and how it needs to be displayed. If all of the data can be collated, then yes you can just `UNION` or `JOIN`. Otherwise you won't have a choice but to make multiple db calls.